# Ask for google authenticator before password

Tags: server, ssh, login, password, pam

I recently configured my server to use the google authenticator pam alongside user passwords.
In order to protect users that reuse passwords is it possible to ask for the users TOTP before asking the user for their password?
Is it a good idea to do this if its possible?

using ubuntu server 20.04 focal